# Python voter turnout assignment - class and object

Tags: python, class, object

I need to write a code to turn out the name of the County which: (i) has the highest voter turnout and (ii) percentage of population voted. Can you help me because I'm so confused. Here is what I have done:

```
class County: 
   def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters) :
   self.population = init_population
   self.voters = init_voters

allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]  

def highest_turnout(self):
   highest = self[0]
   highest_voters = self[0].voters
   for county in data:
      if county.voters > highest_voters:
         highest = county

result = highest_turnout(self)
print(result)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In `highest_turnout` you have to `return highest`. Then instead of passing in `self` to `highest_turnout` you must pass in `data`

Comment: Burhan Khalid my question is "write a code to turn out the name of the County which: (i) has the highest voter turnout and (ii) percentage of population voted". And I'm stuck with the code to make comparison and print the result

Comment: Hi Primusa, where should I put the return highest?

Comment: Hi @TranMaiCo, the `return highest` would be added as the last line in function `def highest_turnout(data):`, aligned/indented under the `for` statement. Then you would change your call as `result = highest_turnout(data)`

Comment: as an aside, your function could be simplified to a one line calculation `largest_percent_voted = max([i.voters/i.population for i in data])`

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing suggestions from comments, the `highest_turnout` function needs to `return` the `highest` otherwise after the function finishes the `highest` value is lost. 
Then instead of passing in `self` to `highest_turnout` pass in `data`:

```
class County:
    def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters):
        self.name = init_name
        self.population = init_population
        self.voters = init_voters

allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)

data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]  

def highest_voter_turnout(data):
    '''iterate over county objects comparing county.voters values; 
    returns county object with max voters attribute'''
    highest_voters = data[0]
    for county in data:
        if county.voters > highest_voters.voters:
            highest_voters = county
    return highest_voters

result_highest_voter_turnout = highest_voter_turnout(data)

print(result_highest_voter_turnout.name)
```

So far, this will return and display the name of the "County which: (i) has the highest voter turnout" (i.e. `allegheny`).

A similar function can now be created to compute the county with the highest "(ii) percentage of population voted" (one method also mentioned in comments).